# QSqlField name() method returns ""

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I have a class (`ServicesTableModel`) which inherits from `QSqlRelationalTableModel`. In the constructor I have:

```
ServicesTableModel::ServicesTableModel( QWidget* parent, QSqlDatabase db )
: QSqlRelationalTableModel( parent, db )
{ 
    setTable( "servicios" );
    select();
    ...
}
```

Now, if I place the line

```
qDebug() << primaryKey();
```

where the dots are I get

```
QSqlRecord( 1 ) 
" 0:" QSqlField("ser_id", int, required: no, generated: yes)
```

which makes perfect sense, but after

```
qDebug() << primaryKey().name();
```

the answer is

""

so I can't reach the name of the primary key.

The table is sqlite, defined with

```
CREATE TABLE servicios (ser_id integer primary key, ... )
```

This matters because I'm trying to generalize the class for objects closely related to the rows in a table, and it seems natural not to have to provide the primary key name to the constructor.

I must surely be doing something wrong, or I don't understand what the `name()_` method from `QSqlField` does.

Comment: QSqlField has a _name()_ method, but _primaryKey()_ returns a QSqlIndex object and it is its _name()_ method that I was calling. That's why I didn't get an answer.
After _setTable( tableName )_ QSqlTableModel gets its primary key alright, but to get its name (well, the name of the field, which is what I needed, so I could feed just an index number to the constructor of my class), if it is a one field key, one has to call _primaryKey().fieldName(0)_.
So I only had to pay a bit more atention and read the docs after some rest. 
I know. It should be a lesson to me.
I hope I lost nobody's time.

Comment: it's perfectly ok to answer your own question in an answer, so others can upvote it.

Comment: You should be careful with QSqlRelationalTableModel. It seems that after you set relations `name()` will return the name of the field from `relation table` and not from original table.

Answer (score 1):

`primaryKey.name()` returns the name of the index.

In SQL, an index can be named, and this is independent from the name of the field(s) used for the key.

An index can work on several fields.
Each field name can be retrieved with `key.fieldName(i)`, with `0<i<key.count()`